# Running bazel with sandboxing in a Docker container

Tags: docker, sandbox, bazel

I want to build with bazel within a Docker container. However, I always get the following warning:

> WARNING: Sandboxed execution is not supported on your system and thus
>   hermeticity of actions cannot be guaranteed. See
>   http://bazel.io/docs/bazel-user-manual.html#sandboxing for more
>   information. You can turn off this warning via
>   --ignore_unsupported_sandboxing.

I do want to use sandboxing. I understand that this is a privilege issue and this happens because some privileges are dropped by the Docker daemon. What privileges do I need so sandboxing works?

Note: Simply using `--privileged` is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be able to use user namespaces inside the docker container. I remember that before docker 1.10 this was not possible except by using `--privileged` but now that user namespaces are used for docker it might be possible.